# Get Long from a string using Scala

Tags: scala

I was wondering what is the best way to obtain a Long from a string that may have other characters in it as well.

For example, "dd:rrrt:r:6564" will become 6564

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scala> "dd:rrrt:r:6564".filter(_.isDigit).toLong
res0: Long = 6564
```

Comment: Nice :), I was thinking of using regex, but this is much better

Comment: @flavian In Scala `String` is enhanced with `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps`. This is done via an implicit conversion in `scala.Predef` that is always in scope. See this: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps

Comment: This might be fine for trusted data, but fails when there are no digits in the string. Depending on the use case, you might be better off in the long run to parse the string (eg, using a regex like Randall Schulz suggested) and explicitly dealing with unexpected formats.

Comment: @KristianDomagala Ya, I'd wrap the whole call in a `Try` call and pattern match on the result.

Answer (score 3):

If you know something about the format or especially if you demand something about that format, then extraction of the numeric substring using `Regex` is handy (I'm making up some semi-generic "picture" format for you example here):

```
val EmbeddedNumberFmt = """\d{2}:\w{4}:\w:(\d+)""".r

val number =
  "12:xyzz:q:6564" match {
    case EmbeddedNumberFmt(n) => Some(n.toLong)
    case _ => None
  }
```

You now have a `Some(n)` (if the input conformed to the format) or `None` (if the input didn't conform to the format).